# Turn camel case fields with numerical digits into snake case using Python

Tags: python, regex

I have the below method in Python (3.10):

```
import re

def camel_to_screaming_snake(value):
    return '_'.join(re.findall('[A-Z][a-z]+|[0-9A-Z]+(?=[A-Z][a-z])|[0-9A-Z]{2,}|[a-z0-9]{2,}|[a-zA-Z0-9]'
                                        , value)).upper()
```

The goal I am trying to accomplish is to insert an underscore every time the case in a string changes, or between a non-numeric character and a numeric character. However, the following cases being passed in are not yielding expected results. (left is what is passed in, right is what is returned)

```
vn3b -> VN3B
vnRbb250V -> VN_RBB_250V
```

I am expecting the following return values:

```
vn3b -> VN_3_B
vnRbb250V -> VN_RBB_250_V
```

What is wrong with my regex preventing this from working as expected?

Comment: It's not clear why you expected otherwise. I'd recommend using a regex debugger, e.g. https://regex101.com/r/P0HdBq/1.

Comment: The reason why I expected otherwise is because I am unfamiliar with regex (and how to use the debugger you passed along, for that matter). I was hoping someone would be able to provide the correct regex with an explanation of where I went wrong. The very presence of this question indicates that.

Comment: Then you could have a look at e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/4736/3001761. A post for every possible use regex can be put to isn't the valuable Q&A SO is optimising for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to catch particular boundaries and insert an `_` in them. To find a boundary, you can use the following regex format: `(?<=<before>)(?=<after>)`. These are non capturing lookaheads and lookbehinds where `before` and `after` are replaced with the conditions.

In this case you have defined 3 ways that you might need to find a boundary:

- A lowercase letter followed by an uppercase letter: `(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])`
- A number followed by a letter: `(?<=[0-9])(?=[a-zA-Z])`
- A letter followed by a number: `(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=[0-9])`

You can combine these into a single regex with an or `|` and then call `sub` on it to replace the boundaries. Afterwards you can uppercase the output:

```
import re

boundaries_re = re.compile(
    r"((?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z]))"
    r"|((?<=[0-9])(?=[a-zA-Z]))"
    r"|((?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=[0-9]))"
)

def format_var(text):
    return boundaries_re.sub("_", text).upper()
```

```
>>> format_var("vn3b")
VN_3_B
>>> format_var("vnRbb250V")
VN_RBB_250_V
```

Comment: Perfect. I wasn't familiar with boundaries. Thanks for pointing out compiling in advance as well for improved performance.